# Background not shown on DIV with 2 Divs Html

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a "container" DIV which has 2 floating DIV's with different height inside, and when I apply the background property on the "container" DIV it doesnt work.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/arthurg/XUmsU/

How can I show the background on the container (using CSS)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  overflow:hidden; to the container. Like this:

```
#container{
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/XUmsU/1/

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>

#container{
   height:100%;
   background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

#left{
   width:100px;
   background:green;
   height:30px;
   float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear floats.

Add this `<br style="clear: both"/>` after those two floating divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <br style="clear: both"/>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XUmsU/3/

There is other (new) methods for clearfix ([with pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)).